# Generating a ServicePartitionKey using MD5 Hashing Algorithm seldomly return WindowsCryptographicException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, stateful

We are using MD5 Hashing Algorithm for generating PartitionKey to route to a stateful Service.
For quite sometime we haven't seen any concerning issues in this approach.
But, upgrading to .NET 6 we are seldomly seeing WindowsCryptographicException in the logs while trying to route to Stateful Service.

Area/Component:
Stateful Services, PartitionKey generator

To Reproduce

private readonly MD5 _md5 = MD5.Create();

```
public long GetPartitionKey(string Id)
{
    var bytesToHash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{Id}");

    var hash = _md5.ComputeHash(bytesToHash);
    var key = BitConverter.ToInt64(hash, 0);
    return key;
}
```

Expected behavior
Shouldn't be returning any error.
Observed behavior:
{"Type":"WindowsCryptographicException","Message":"Unknown error (0xc1000008)","StackTrace":" at Internal.Cryptography.HashProviderCng.AppendHashData(ReadOnlySpan`1 source) at Internal.Cryptography.HashProvider.AppendHashData(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Byte[] buffer)
Screenshots
If applicable, add screenshots to help explain your problem.

Service Fabric Runtime Version:
8.0

Environment:

Azure
Linux
If this is a regression, which version did it regress from?
After upgrading to .NET6

Answer (score 0):

*We used .NET6 with stateful service and used the MD5 Hashing algorithm, able to run and deployed without any exceptions*

*Try to run the Visual studio as `"Administrator"`
Below are the Service Fabric versions installed**

[image]
[image]

[image]

*Used the GetPartitionKey code with MD5*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But just to clear it out it never throws any exception for me during build & deploy both in my local luster or in the cloud. It works absolutely fine for most of the time. But, it occassionally (with very less probability) keeps failing in cloud throwing this windowscryptographicexception. If you deployed it on cloud, try observing the logs.

Comment: I do not find any exception in logs after deploying to azure also.